# best way to quickly share multiple photos without permanently hosting them

Tags: photos

I find that I'm often asked to share lots of photos with someone, enough that uploading each one individually to them gets tedious when I would like to drag and drop the whole bunch.  I could put them on photobucket, but some of them are semi-private; private enough that I don't want them to be easily found on image hosting sites.

Are there any convenient ways of sharing these photos quickly but still being able to remove them from the inter-webs afterwards (without too much hassle)?  I have found Yahoo Messenger complete version has great photo sharing options; but not everyone has it and I can't expect people to download it just to see some photos.

Comment: If you only need to share with one person, why not just zip the pictures and email them to them?

Comment: the files tend to be too large if I want to send more then a few photos.  Also, many people use tablets or phones that lack the ability to unzip them (or maybe jsut aren't intuitive to unzip; in either case many can't unzip thigs on their tablets).

Comment: I haven't found a device yet that doesn't have an unzip app available. :)  If the file is too large to email, there are services like sendbigfiles.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has picasaweb.google.com

free download picasa from google.
install picasa
set the default privacy options.
Under the file menu you can "add folders to picasa"
tick off the folders you want added.

Then click on each folder and select the "sync to web" option in the upper right hand corner.
It will show you the current sharing options to verify they are correct.

While picasa is uploading goto picasaweb.google.com
and add the people you want to share the pictures with.

Answer (score 0):

As @techie007 stated, zipping your photos and sending them through e-mail is a good way to share photos.

Main advantages:

- Only you and the persons you sent the e-mail have the photos.
- They aren't "hosted" (i.e. only those that can access their e-mails can see them).
- If you don't trust your e-mail provider you can just delete the sent e-mail (this, however, doesn't delete the files on the other end - assuming anyone sees any file on the net, anyone can store them).
- Can *bulk* select and send (depending on how well you use your OS).

Answer (score 0):

Get a Dropbox or Ubuntu One Account.
Then zip the folder with all the images you want to share and upload it to the cloud. When done, right click the zip and select the option to generate a  "public link". This link will allow everyone who knows it to download your zipped file (if nobody knows the link, nobody can download the zip).

Send your friends the link.
Done.

Comment: A *problem* with this is that if someone else gets the link then that someone else can also see the pictures. On the plus side, I think Dropbox recognizes (or at least has an option to) picture folders as galleries and displays them accordingly.

Comment: Nobody can see the content. Only if you or someone you gave the link gives the link to someone else it is possible to get the linked content. The link method is save.

Comment: thank you doktoro for mentining that dropbox recognizes photos.  I was going to dismiss it as to unintuitive for end-users if dropbox couldn't automatically display photos.